# is it necessary to uninstall python 3.7 to run python 2.7?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv3.0

I am using the visual studio for opencv. using python. I have downloaded the code from [here](http://hanzratech.in/2015/05/30/local-binary-patterns.html). my friend corrected the code and run on his desktop computer. but When I run that code on my laptop. it give me syntax error. i have uninstall python3.7 and install python2.7 and all the libraries. but it gives the error.
I am running the code through cmd through python2.7
please guide.

I am writing this `c:\Users\babar\Desktop\texture-matching-master\perform-training.py -t c:\users\babar\Desktop\texture-matching-master\data\lbp\train\ -l c:\Users\babar\Desktop\texture-matching-master\data\lbp\class_train.txt`

getting error : 
syntax error: invalid syntax

Comment: No, it is not necessary to uninstall python 3.7 to use python 2.7 and vice versa. Maybe you should check linked libraries in your project settings?

Comment: Also you could attach error message to the question. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Piotrowy please check now sir.

Comment: so can we set the environment variable of python2.7 when python3.7 is already set? 
@Piotrowy

Comment: when you run the file just choose which one to use